# Reboot agent as a build step or dependency in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there a way to restart the agent machine during the build of a job in TeamCity - if so, how can this be achieved?

I tried adding a dependency job or a build step with "shutdown -r -f -t 0" but then TeamCity reports the build has been canceled since it can no longer communicate with the agent until it reboots and causes another agent to take over the build.

When clicking restart a confirm pop up shows. When I use `Curl` I can't find the actual link. How do I click the confirm link? It looks the same!

```
curl -u username:password "http://TeamCityServerURL/agentDetails.html?id=2&agentTypeId=3&realAgentName=ip_10.0.0.1"

wget –method POST "http://TeamCityServerURL/agentDetails.html?id=2&agentTypeId=3&realAgentName=ip_10.0.0.1" –http-user=Username –http-password=password –header="Content-Length: 0" -O - -S
```

Comment: What's the point of rebooting the agent machine? Is it crucial that it be part of the build or is it just supposed to be cleanup at the end?

Comment: The vm must reboot to join an AD domain, it must collect build information from there

Comment: The agent is a VM that is dynamically provisioned on a cloud, the image can't be prejoined, joining requires a power cycle on a windows OS. I digress on ur -1

Comment: That begs the question, what is it doing that it needs to be on the domain to run a build?

Comment: What does that matter !!!   It has to collect information! sync code! and publish artifacts! in the domain, some that I can think of as tasks needed in the domain

Comment: What you want to do may not be possible, in which case finding an alternative way to do it would presumably be something you'd want to do. The more information we have the better able to offer suggestions we will be. Like, syncing your code with Github, and letting TeamCity handle the artifacts itself and the build server will store them. Also [this may be relevant](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/seamlessly-join-ec2-instances-to-a-domain/)

Answer (score 3):

I am able to reboot the agent using the following curl request.

```
curl -u User:Password -X POST "http://MyTeamCityServerURL/remoteAccess/reboot.html?agent=2&rebootAfterBuild=true"
```

Comment: curl -s http://teamcityServer/guestAuth/app/rest/agents | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//agents/agent[@name="YOUR_AGENT_NAME"]/@id'

Answer (score 2):

Here is the related request in TeamCity issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36298.
Since 9.0 it is possible to reboot agent manually from UI using "Reboot Agent Machine" link on Agent details page. As workaround you can reboot agent from the build script by emulating a browser request send on manual action invocation from UI.

Comment: I need to automate this, I wonder if this would work, if the agent was dynamically provisioned. What would the POST query parameters look like!

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar requirement, to reset the USB stack periodically on MacOS because Mac's USB stack is unreliable (Android devices that work perfectly with Linux or Windows).

We had a prerequisite task with these options:

- Run build on the same agent
- On failed dependency: make build failed to start
- On failed to start/canceled dependency: make build failed to start

that ran 'shutdown -r now' and immediately reported success to the server using the 'echo #teamcity...' system, trying to catch the small time gap between the reboot actually starting, and the echo sent to the server.

Unfortunately, there's a short time between the script completing and the agent actually rebooting when TeamCity tries to start a new job on the agent, so we have a load of aborted builds - they're restarted, so they don't exactly break anything, but they clutter up the log.

We tried replacing that with the following, which marks the agent as rebooting, and then delegates the shutdown command to a background task which awaits for the TeamCity task to complete before issuing the shutdown:

```
echo "Running: '/sbin/shutdown -r shortly'"
echo rebooting=yes >> $HOME/buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties

CONFIG_PROPERTIES=$(grep teamcity.configuration.properties.file $TEAMCITY_BUILD_PROPERTIES_FILE | cut -d= -f2)
TC_SERVER=$(grep teamcity.serverUrl $CONFIG_PROPERTIES | cut -d= -f2)
BUILD_ID=$(grep teamcity.build.id $CONFIG_PROPERTIES | cut -d= -f2)
STATUS=$( echo "${TC_SERVER}/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:${BUILD_ID}"|tr -d \\ )
echo Polling $STATUS in background until parent task cannot be confirmed still running.

((
  while true; do
    sleep 5
    if curl -s $STATUS | xmllint --xpath "//build/@running" - | grep true ; then
      :
    else
      echo "passw0rd" | /usr/bin/sudo -p "" -S /sbin/shutdown -r now
    fi
  done
) 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &)&
```

I added a step into the machine's reboot process to remove the 'rebooting' parameter at some point before the agent is started back up. (This is a Mac, so I added a plist into /Library/LaunchDemon running

```
/usr/bin/sed -i~ -e /rebooting=yes/d /Users/qa/buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties
```

with logfile directory painstakingly made writable to the appropriate user - plist silently fails otherwise...)

Unfortunately, TeamCity doesn't seem to notice the 'rebooting' parameter with the new 9.1 version, so we had to add an extra dependency between this reboot step and the real task: This new task simply waits until it can't see the 'rebooting' parameter in the configuration file, and half the time it's cancelled and rescheduled - which is fine, because it keeps the 'cancelled' messages out of the main build's log, and that's all we wanted:

```
echo This task runs after the reboot script, as a buffer between the reboot script and the real reboot.
echo That is, THIS task will get all the INTERRUPTED errors, not the real scripts.

echo Uptime:
uptime

echo Infinite loop until machine reboot, unless reboot is already complete:
while grep rebooting=yes $HOME/buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties; do
  echo $(date) Awaiting reboot to interrupt task and clear rebooting=yes from buildAgent.properties file.
  sleep 15
done
```

---

Apparently, copying the buildAgent.properties file then moving the copy on top of the original makes the 9.x agent notice the change, obviating the need for this intermediate step so long as your following build task knows to wait for the 'rebooting=yes' parameter to be deleted by the boot process. I haven't tried it, but that would definitely be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a need to reboot a (non-cloud) build agent as the last step of a build; as the build installed software on the agent that needed a reboot.

However it's a Windows build agent - so had to do this in PowerShell or as a batch script.

Using the TeamCity 9.x [REST API documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-Agents) and the [Accessing Server by HTTP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP) I was able to construct a simple two line PowerShell build step.

The first request gets the Agent Id of the agent running the build (the agent where software was being installed). The second request uses the same Agent Id to reboot the agent.

Authentication credentials are Configuration Parameters for the build, with username and password values that can do httpAuth to TeamCity.

Thanks to [Ivan Leonenko's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367287/ivan-leonenko) [Blog post](https://ileonenko.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/start-teamcity-build-via-web-request-with-powershell-script/) on getting the Authorization headers correct and the use of `[System.Net.WebRequest]`

```powershell
$username = "%buildAgentAccessUser%"
$password = "%buildAgentAccessPassword%"
$authInfo = $username + ":" + $password
$authInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($authInfo))

$uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/name:%teamcity.agent.name%/id"

$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
$webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true 
[System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
[string] $id = $sr.ReadToEnd();
Write-Output "Rebooting Agent ID: $id"

$uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/remoteAccess/reboot.html?agent=$id&rebootAfterBuild=true"

$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
$webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true 
[System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
$sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This was my last build step and reboots the agent after the build is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Lantrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244008/lantrix) solution, just needed to set request method to `post`.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$auth = "%username%:%password%"
$auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($auth))
$uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/agents/name:%teamcity.agent.name%/id"
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $auth
$request.PreAuthenticate = $true 
[System.Net.WebResponse] $response = $request.GetResponse();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $response.GetResponseStream();
[string] $id = $streamReader.ReadToEnd();
Write-Output "Trigger reboot of Agent ID: $id"
$uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/remoteAccess/reboot.html?agent=$id&rebootAfterBuild=true"
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$request.Method="POST"
$request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $auth
$request.PreAuthenticate = $true 
[System.Net.WebResponse] $response = $request.GetResponse();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $response.GetResponseStream();
[string] $response = $streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an adaptation of the PowerShell script from @lantrix that reboots *all* agents instead of just the current agent. Make it a separate project in TeamCity and trigger it with a schedule to for example have daily reboots of all your build agents.

```
$username = "myUserName"
$password = "myPassword"
$authInfo = $username + ":" + $password
$authInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($authInfo))

$uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/app/rest/agents"

# Query which agents there are
$webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
$webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
$webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true 
[System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
[System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
[xml] $unitsXml = $sr.ReadToEnd();

# Schedule a reboot for every agent
$idNodes = $unitsXml.SelectNodes("//*[@id]")
foreach ($node in $idNodes) {
    $id = $node.attributes['id'].value
    $name = $node.attributes['name'].value
    
    Write-Output "Scheduling reboot for agent $name with ID $id"
    
    $uri = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/httpAuth/remoteAccess/reboot.html?agent=$id&rebootAfterBuild=true"
    
    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $webRequest.Method="POST"
    $webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + $authInfo
    $webRequest.PreAuthenticate = $true 
    [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
    $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
    $sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```